# Call JS function before redirect

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

The situation is as follows:
A user on the client side enters some data and presses a command button that initiates an ajax request. Depending on the input data the JSF Bean on the server side redirects to different pages. But in addition the HTML5 features localstorage respectively sessionstorage should be updated on client side, also depending on the results from the bean. For the storage some data entered from the user is necessary, so that the java script for the storage has to be within the original page.

Now, the problem seems to be that after the response the redirect is always done first, before executing the js function and so it is not possible to access the input data from the user on the client side of curse.

I tried things for calling the js function after pressing the command button like "oncomplete" on the client side using callback parameters (redirect takes place earlier) or RequestContext.execute from the server side (but this internally also uses the oncomplete event i think).
One possible solution I could imagine is to use window.onunload on client side and a hidden input formular to get the result of the bean. But isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect by JS instead of by JSF. Return `null` from action method so that it returns to the same page and then execute the following script to perform a redirect in JS.

```
window.location = newURL;
```

Comment: Ok, under normal circumstances this seems very plausible, but there is also an other aspect that makes it more complicated: the bean is redirecting to an error servlet with an error message in case of an error. For sure this all is manageable in js for example with callback parameters for the redirection url and the possible error message but I don't know if i should be really happy with this solution.
There is no possibility to write directly to the localstore/sessionstore with jsf or primefaces with the response from the server, is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use PrimeFaces with JSF then it's possible to make global override of **PrimeFaces.ajax.ResponseProcessor.doRedirect** in javascript to put any custom code before actual redirect happens:

```
PrimeFaces.ajax.ResponseProcessor.doRedirect = function(node) {

   // <<<< your code is here >>>>

   window.location = node.getAttribute('url');
}
```

Put this code in some js file and include it in all your pages.